# Three.js Raycaster works with mouse not with touch

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have an annoying problem where my raycasting is fine with the mouse but not with touch.

I setup events as such

```
   $(document).bind('mousedown', onDocumentMouseDown);
   $(document).bind('mousewheel', onDocumentMouseWheel);
   $(document).bind('touchstart', onDocumentTouchStart);
   $(document).bind('touchmove', onDocumentTouchMove);
```

My mouse event

```
    function onDocumentMouseDown(e) {

    e.preventDefault();
    detectHotspotClick(e.pageX,e.pageY);

}
```

My Touch event

```
function onDocumentTouchStart(e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    var event = e.originalEvent;

    if (event.touches.length == 1) {
        var t=event.touches[0];
        draggingY = t.pageY;
        detectHotspotClick(t.pageX,t.pageY);
    }

    if (event.touches.length == 2) {

        var dx = event.touches[ 0 ].pageX - event.touches[ 1 ].pageX;
        var dy = event.touches[ 0 ].pageY - event.touches[ 1 ].pageY;
        _touchZoomDistanceEnd = _touchZoomDistanceStart = Math.sqrt( dx * dx + dy * dy );

    }
}
```

My detection

```
function detectHotspotClick(x,y){

    console.log('detectHotspotClick('+ x + "," + y+ ")" );

    var raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
    var mouse = new THREE.Vector2();

    mouse.x =  ( x / renderer.domElement.width ) * 2 - 1;
    mouse.y = - ( y / renderer.domElement.height ) * 2 + 1;

    raycaster.setFromCamera( mouse, camera );

    var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects( targetList, true );

    if ( intersects.length > 0)
        hotspotClick(intersects[ 0 ].object);
}
```

This works fine with mouse, but I notice on Touch, the mouse.x value always seems to be negetative and I'm not sure that's right.

Is there any other way of doing this I should consider?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why.. but it works with   detectHotspotClick(t.pageX*2,t.pageY*2) on the touchevent, which must report different figures to the mouse event.